# Image lazy loading doesn't work as excepted - the browser preloads the images instead

Tags: javascript, svelte, swiper.js

How can I set up and use lazy loading for slider images instead of preloading them on page load? I'm trying to follow the details [in this documentation](https://v8.swiperjs.com/swiper-api#lazy-loading). However, it doesn't seem to work as expected.

As you can see, these are the images that have been loaded after the DOM loaded. How can I prevent this with the lazy loading that swiper offers? Should I use `loading="lazy"` on the images theirselves?

[image]

This is the code that I'm using (Svelte):

```
import { Pagination, Navigation, Autoplay, Keyboard, Lazy } from "swiper";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/svelte';

import "swiper/css/navigation";
import "swiper/css/pagination";
import "swiper/css/lazy";

let modules = [Pagination, Autoplay, Lazy];
...
    <Swiper
        on:swiper={(e) => swiper = e.detail[0]}
        loop={loop}
        lazy={{
            loadPrevNext: true,
        }}
        preloadImages={false}
        spaceBetween={0}
        slidesPerView={1}
        modules={modules}
    >
        {#each image_urls as image_url}
            <SwiperSlide>
                <img class="w-full object-cover cursor-pointer swiper-lazy" src={image_url} alt="house" loading="lazy">
                <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
            </SwiperSlide>
        {/each}
    </Swiper>
```

Answer (score -1):

The latest Swiper library v9 doesn't contain a Svelte folder. Hence, importing swiper/svelte causes a dependency error. However, you can use a pure JavaScript implementation. Make sure you create a Swiper instance inside the onMount hook. If you are interested in a comparison between the native lazy load and vanilla-lazyload implementation I wrote a blog post about [how to do lazy loading in Swiper.js](https://batdogcodes.com/blog/how-lazy-loading-in-an-image-slider-can-improve-performance-and-user-experience)

```
<script>
    import Swiper, { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper';
    import 'swiper/css';
    import 'swiper/css/navigation';
    import 'swiper/css/pagination';
    import { onMount, onDestroy } from 'svelte';
    import Image1 from '$lib/images/joshua-sortino-f3uWi9G-lus-unsplash.jpg';
    import Image2 from '$lib/images/joshua-sortino-gii7lF4y0WY-unsplash.jpg';
    import Image3 from '$lib/images/joshua-sortino-xZqr8WtYEJ0-unsplash.jpg';
    import Image4 from '$lib/images/richard-dorran-pyIGuqVX6k4-unsplash.jpg';

    let images = [{ src: Image1 }, { src: Image2 }, { src: Image3 }, { src: Image4 }];
    let swiper;

    onMount(() => {
        swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
            lazy: true,
            modules: [Navigation, Pagination],
            pagination: {
                el: '.swiper-pagination',
                clickable: true
            },
            navigation: {
                nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
            }
        });
    });

    onDestroy(() => {
        if (!swiper) return;
        swiper.destroy();
    });
</script>

<div class="container">
    <h2>Native lazy load</h2>
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            {#each images as image}
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img src={image.src} alt="" loading="lazy" />
                    <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader swiper-lazy-preloader-white" />
                </div>
            {/each}
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next" />
        <div class="swiper-button-prev" />
        <div class="swiper-pagination" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on image that has been attached, you need to turn off Disable Cache on your browser network. Cache image and asset doesn't work when Disable Cache has been enabled.
[image]